# self.connect() vs QMainWindow.connect()

Tags: python, pyqt4

playing as a newbie with pyQT4 `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`, I realized that in all my simple cases there is actually no difference between `<class>.connect(...)` and `self.connect(...)` , meaning that both do what I want.
Most simple case would be connecting a Button of a QWindow like in the title of the question.

Is there a difference and can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Possibly `self` will only connect the current instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect` method you're refering to is acutally [`QObject.connect`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#connect), which is a static method. So it doesn't really matter if you call it on an instance or a subclass of QObject or on QObject directly.

That said, don't use it.

It's better to use the connect method of the signal instead:

```
qobject_instance.signal_name.connect(slot_or_callable)
```

This is referred to as ["new style signals"](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), and it's the preferred way of connecting signals in PyQt4.
In PyQt5 the old style signals are even gone completely, that means `QObject.connect` doesn't exist anymore and you *must* use new style signals.

Comment: Ok, so it just inherited from a higher class. The `QObject.connect` always looked strange to me; so I think that the PyQt5 style is definitively better and more intuitive. As @ekhumoro pointed out, it is unfortunate that `pyuic4` is not doing this.

Comment: pyuic from PyQt5 does, so if you want you can switch to Qt5... :)

Comment: In the near future I will dump XP and pythonXY with it. After fully switching to linux, I guess that PyQt5 will be the one.

Answer (score 2):

The use of SIGNAL and SLOT should be avoided. Although this style of connecting signals is still supported in PyQt4, it not supported at all in PyQt5.

Instead, you should use the [new-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) whenever possible. The new-style syntax is much more readable and less error-prone than the old-style syntax.

To illustrate the difference, consider this [QTreeWidget signal](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#currentItemChanged):

> void QTreeWidget::currentItemChanged ( QTreeWidgetItem * current,
>   QTreeWidgetItem * previous ) [signal]

Using the old-style syntax, in PyQ4 it could be translated as:

```
    self.connect(self.treewidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(
        'currentItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem *, QTreeWidgetItem *)'),
        self.handleCurrentChanged)
```

but using the new-style syntax it could be:

```
   self.treewidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.handleCurrentChanged)
```

which is immediately much simpler and clearer, and makes it obvious what is being connected to what, and how.

Even better, it is much less error-prone. If you get a new-style connection wrong, it will always raise an error. With the old-style syntax, if the string argument to `SIGNAL` is slightly wrong, the connection will fail silently, making it very awkward to debug.

PS:

If you use `pyuic4` to convert designer ui files to python modules, the generated code will use the old-style syntax. This is unfortunate, but it obviously had to be done this way for backward-compatibility reasons. It does not imply that this is the "right" way to do things in hand-written PyQt code.

Comment: I noticed the problem with the string argument more than once. The new style is more intuitive and I'll try using this from now on. The example really makes it clear. The `pyuic4` style is unfortunate, but up to a certain point I understand backward compatibility issues. Maybe one could put a switch.